# Created cron job on cyber panel but it is not working

Tags: php, cron, cron-task, cyber-panel

I have created a cron job but nothing is happening neither i am able to see the error logs I am working on cyber panel.

here is what I posted on command input field

```
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/lsphp  /home/domainname.com/public_html/demo/run-greedier-cron.php
```

I am not pretty much sure what exactly is happening and what is the problem going on can anyone help me out please

Comment: Check the permissions of your PHP file and ensure that it is executable. You can do this by running the command `chmod +x /home/domainname.com/public_html/demo/run-greedier-cron.php`

Comment: wher edo i run this command can you please tell me secondly i ran this file on my browser and it's working fine

Comment: @AnasSafi file permission is 077

Comment: please try in terminal run this command `/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/lsphp  /home/domainname.com/public_html/demo/run-greedier-cron.php`

Comment: ohh ok let me try connecting with ssh then cute ftp

Comment: Yes, you should connect to ssh to make sure that the command works in the terminal

Comment: I got the same problem on cyberpanel and I solved it opening in SSH -> nano the cron file and saving it again manually.